# Zenity form for easy network configuration

Tags: bash, shell-script, zenity

Im doing a zenity form for easy network configuration. The end user just fills in the information and the script does the rest.
 Is there a better way to do this? 
Any input from you guys is welcome.
Thanks

```
sudo sed -i.bak '7,8 d' /etc/network/interfaces
sudo sed -i '/inet netmask/d' /etc/network/interfaces
sudo sed -i '/inet nameservers/d' /etc/network/interfaces
sudo sed -i '/inet address/d' /etc/network/interfaces
sudo sed -i '/inet gateway/d' /etc/network/interfaces
sudo sed -i "8a iface eth0 inet static" /etc/network/interfaces
ip=$(zenity --entry --title="Ip adress" --text="Ip adress:")
sudo sed -i "9a address $ip" /etc/network/interfaces
mask=$(zenity --entry --title="Netmask" --text="Netmask address:")
sudo sed -i "11a netmask $mask" /etc/network/interfaces
gateway=$(zenity --entry --title="Gateway address" --text="Gateway address:")
sudo sed -i "10a gateway $gateway" /etc/network/interfaces
dns=$(zenity --entry --title="Dns" --text="Dns address:")
sudo sed -i "12a dns-nameservers $dns" /etc/network/interfaces
sudo sed -i "13a iface eth1 inet static" /etc/network/interfaces
sudo sed -i "14a address $ip" /etc/network/interfaces
sudo sed -i "15a gateway $gateway" /etc/network/interfaces
sudo sed -i "16a netmask $mask" /etc/network/interfaces
sudo sed -i "17a dns-nameservers $dns" /etc/network/interfaces
zenity --question --text "Is the information accurate"; echo $?
 if [ $? > 0 ];
    then
        echo "--- do it again ---"
        sudo cp home/Test/interfaces /etc/network/ #this copies a interfaces.bak 
                                                    #over the changed one
        sleep 3s
        exit
    fi
```

Now i changed to this:

```
cp /etc/network/interfaces /tmp/interfaces
sed -i -e '7,8 d' \
       -e '/inet address/d '\
       -e '/inet netmask/d' \
       -e '/inet nameservers/d' \
       -e '/inet gateway/d' \
       -e '/iface eth0 inet static/d' \
       -e '/iface eth1 inet static/d' /tmp/interfaces
sudo sed -i "8a iface eth0 inet static" /tmp/interfaces
ip=$(zenity --entry --title="Ip adress" --text="Ip adress:")
sudo sed -i "9a address $ip" /tmp/interfaces
mask=$(zenity --entry --title="Netmask" --text="Netmask address:")
sudo sed -i "10a netmask $mask" /tmp/interfaces
gateway=$(zenity --entry --title="Gateway address" --text="Gateway address:")
sudo sed -i "11a gateway $gateway"/tmp/interfaces
dns=$(zenity --entry --title="Dns" --text="Dns address:")
sudo sed -i "12a dns-nameservers $dns" /tmp/interfaces
sudo sed -i "13a iface eth1 inet static" /tmp/interfaces
sudo sed -i "14a address $ip" /tmp/interfaces
sudo sed -i "15a gateway $gateway" /tmp/interfaces
sudo sed -i "16a netmask $mask" /tmp/interfaces
sudo sed -i "17a dns-nameservers $dns" /tmp/interfaces
wait 1s;
sudo zenity --text-info --height=500 --width=400 < <(cat /tmp/interfaces)
if ! zenity --question --text "Är alla addresser rätt ifyllda";  then
    cp /tmp/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces 
    exit
    fi
```

And nothing happens... no changes to the file whatsoever..
 help? :D

Comment: First of all, you don't use `sudo` in a script, run the script itself as root if you need it. Are you creating a `bash` script here?

Comment: use `if ! zenity --question --text "Is the information accurate" ; then …`

Comment: I recommend http://www.shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run the *script* with `sudo`.  Don't prefix every single command with `sudo`. Alternatively, make a copy of `/etc/network/interfaces` as non-root and work on that and then use `sudo` to copy it back into place.
2. `sed ...; sed ...; sed ...` may be replaced by `sed -e '...' -e '...' -e '...'`.
3. Testing on `$?` is not needed.

So what you get is

```
cp /etc/network/interfaces /tmp/interfaces
sed -i -e '7,8 d' \
       -e '/inet netmask/d' \
       -e '/inet nameservers/d \
       (etc.)
       -e '8a iface eth0 inet static' /tmp/interfaces
(etc.)

if ! zenity --question --text "Is the information accurate"; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: check the main question please.. i have an issue .. and i cant really explain it :)

Comment: @hibridpc I was making a guess on the `if` test. You may have to remove the `!`.  Also, you still have way too many `sed` invocations.  If you set `ip`, `gateway` and `mask` at the beginning, you should be ok with just one `sed`.

Comment: why do i get "file not found" when  i write this command in shell?sudo sed -i '7a iface eth0 inet static' /tmp/interfaces \;

Comment: sudo sed -i '7a iface eth0 inet static' /tmp/interfaces \;

Comment: @hibridpc You are trying to run `sed` on a file called `;`.